# Differentiate between multiple registration pages for same user model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, registration

I have a fairly vanilla registration system for my Rails 4 app, and I'd like to add a strange feature.  I'd like to provide multiple registration forms, and secretly set a value on the new User object, based on which page the data is being submitted from.

My current way of doing it is bad for security reasons. It works fine, but a savvy user could use a browser's dev tools to change the value of the hidden field and indicate that they came in from a different page.

**routes.rb**

```
get '/signup', to: 'users#new'
get '/red-signup',  to: 'users#new', color: 'red'
get '/blue-signup',  to: 'users#new', color: 'blue'
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
def new
  @user = User.new
  @color = params[:color] || 'grey'  # default of grey
end
```

**users/new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= f.hidden_field :color, value: @color %>   # VULNERABLE TO TAMPERING
  <%= f.submit "Create my account" %>
<% end %>
```

So, I'd like a tamper-proof way to differentiate between new registrations that came from different pages. I assume that means keeping any signifying tokens out of the form data.

Any suggestions for an approach to explore?

Comment: Do you have a separate page and route for each color ? if so why not making decision based on the url in your controller by checking the value of `request.fullpath` ?

Comment: What about using defaults for that: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/routing.html#defining-defaults , I think it might help you because you will be able to process that in the controller. Let me know if it helped actually, I never used so I'm curious.

So in your case you will have: ```get '/blue-signup',  to: 'users#new', defaults: { color: 'blue' }```

Comment: Ali: I suspect something along these lines will be best.

Comment: Tom Hert: That's basically what I'm doing now, passing the value associated for each route to the #new action. I could use default, but the way I'm handling it in the controller is fine, too. The problem is: that value needs to get to the #create action, and my current solution of passing it in with the rest of the params leaves it too exposed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your aim is to pass the `@color` value safely between `new` and `create` action, you can use the session for this purpose. Inside your `new` action you set the color:

```
def new
  @user = User.new
  session[:color] = params[:color] || 'grey'  # default of grey
end
```

Then in the `create` action you can retrieve it:

```
def create
  @color = session[:color]  
end
```

Rails session data is stored in Cookies by default and is cryptographically signed to make it tamper-proof. It is also encrypted so anyone with access to it can't read its contents.

Answer (score 0):

What is the final purpose?

If it is to know which registration forms has a better conversion rate, you are reinventing the wheel and you should have a look on [A/B testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A/B_testing) and [those gems](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/A_B_Testing) for doing it right.

Comment: As you've probably gathered, the color thing is just an abstraction to make the question clear. But, it's not an A/B testing thing. 

The actual use is for white-labeling reasons, to allow various companies we work with to provide branded registration pages for their employees, and allow us to associate users with their employers.

Comment: "to provide branded registration pages for their employees" what do you mean by different registration pages ? Do you want to modify the style of the page (for example a different background color, a different font, etc.) or do you want to have different field (for example one can ask for the email, another one for a username, another one for an address) ?